# Oidc login infinite loop

Tags: angular, openid-connect, auth0, oidc-client-js

I'm using **Auth0** with **Oidc** in my Angular app for login.

I have the following configurations:

**auth.module**

```
NgOidcClientModule.forRoot({
      // prettier-ignore
      oidc_config: {
        authority: environment.sts.authority,
        client_id: environment.sts.clientId,
        redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-login-redirect-callback.html`,
        scope: 'openid profile',
        response_type: 'id_token token',
        post_logout_redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html`,
        silent_redirect_uri: `${environment.appRoot}oidc-silent-renew-redirect-callback.html`,
        accessTokenExpiringNotificationTime: 10,
        automaticSilentRenew: true,
        metadata: {
          authorization_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}authorize?audience=${environment.sts.audience}`,
          userinfo_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}userinfo`,
          issuer: environment.sts.authority,
          jwks_uri: `${environment.sts.authority}.well-known/jwks.json`,
          // tslint:disable-next-line: max-line-length
          end_session_endpoint: `${environment.sts.authority}v2/logout?returnTo=${environment.appRootEncoded + 'oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html'}&client_id=${environment.sts.clientId}`
        },
        userStore: new WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
      }
    })
```

**environment.ts**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  appRoot: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  appRootEncoded: 'http://localhost:4200/',
  apiUrl: 'http://localhost:4201/',
  sts: {
    authority: 'https://dev-serj.eu.auth0.com/',
    clientId: 'R7fxgHNkPEj2VX1H7q4Fp0j2XnSqaudJ',
    audience: 'dev-serj-api'
  }
};
```

In **Auth0**:

**Allowed Callback URLs:**

- http://localhost:4200/oidc-login-redirect-callback.html
- http://localhost:4200/oidc-silent-renew-redirect-callback.html

**Allowed Web Origins**: http://localhost:4200

**Allowed Logout URLs**: http://localhost:4200/oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html

And the scripts from **oidc HTML** pages are the following ones:

**oidc-login-redirect-callback.html**:

```
<script src="oidc-client.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var config = {
      userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
   };
   var mgr = new Oidc.UserManager(config);
   mgr.signinRedirectCallback().then(
      () => {
        window.history.replaceState({}, window.document.title, windows.location.origin);
        window.location = '/';
      }, error => {
          console.log(error);
      }
   );
</script>
```

**oidc-logout-redirect-callback.html**:

```
<script src="oidc-client.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var Oidc = window.Oidc;
  var config = {
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
  };
  if (Oidc && Oidc.Log && Oidc.Log.logger) {
    Oidc.Log.logger = console;
  }
  var isPopupCallback = JSON.parse(
    window.localStorage.getItem('ngoidc:isPopupCallback')
  );
  if (isPopupCallback) {
    new Oidc.UserManager(config).signoutPopupCallback();
  } else {
    new Oidc.UserManager(config).signoutRedirectCallback().then(test => {
      window.location.href = '/';
    });
  }
</script>
```

**oidc-silent-renew-redirect-callback.html**:

```
<script src="oidc-client.min.js"></script>
<script>
  var config = {
    userStore: new Oidc.WebStorageStateStore({ store: window.localStorage })
  };
  new Oidc.UserManager(config).signinSilentCallback().catch(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
  });
</script>
```

I'm also adding a **Bearer token** using an **HTTP_INTERCEPTOR**.

In **app.module** I've created an **initializeApp** function:

```
export function initializeApp(appInitializerService: AppInitializerService) {
  return (): Promise<void> => {
    return appInitializerService.init();
  };
}
```

which is used in **APP_INITIALIZER**:

```
providers: [
    AppInitializerService,
    {
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
      useFactory: initializeApp,
      deps: [AppInitializerService],
      multi: true
    }
  ],
```

And here I have the **AppInitializerService**:

```
@Injectable()
export class AppInitializerService {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  public async init(): Promise<void> {
    return new Promise(async resolve => {
      await this.authService.init();

      resolve();
    });
  }
}
```

And my **auth.service** also:

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService {
  identity$: Observable<User>;
  loggedIn$: Observable<boolean>;

  constructor(private oidcFacade: OidcFacade) {
    this.identity$ = this.oidcFacade.identity$;
    this.loggedIn$ = this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$;
  }

  public init(): Promise<void> {
    this.oidcFacade.getOidcUser();

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      combineLatest([
        this.oidcFacade.waitForAuthenticationLoaded(),
        this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$
      ])
        .pipe(
          take(1),
          tap(([, loggedIn]) => {
            loggedIn ? resolve() : this.oidcFacade.signinRedirect();
          })
        )
        .subscribe();
    });
  }

  public signOut() {
    this.oidcFacade.signoutRedirect();
  }
}
```

And I can't understand what I'm missing or why I'm into an infinite loop after I'm redirect to login:

```
http://localhost:4200/oidc-login-redirect-callback.html#access_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik16ZzVPRFl5TkROQlJUVkNPRVEwTmpBNE1qUkZORGMxUVROQ1JqTkZOall4TVVJd1JqQTJRUSJ9.eyJpc3MiOiJodHRwczovL2Rldi1zZXJqLmV1LmF1dGgwLmNvbS8iLCJzdWIiOiJhdXRoMHw1ZTA1NDQzMTI4NGQ0NzBlYjkwZDkzNmEiLCJhdWQiOlsiZGV2LXNlcmotYXBpIiwiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtc2Vyai5ldS5hdXRoMC5jb20vdXNlcmluZm8iXSwiaWF0IjoxNTc3NTQ4OTYzLCJleHAiOjE1Nzc1NTYxNjMsImF6cCI6IlI3ZnhnSE5rUEVqMlZYMUg3cTRGcDBqMlhuU3FhdWRKIiwic2NvcGUiOiJvcGVuaWQgcHJvZmlsZSJ9.UGV6tEiAALfQg7qhO0lFBrC_3lZpzbLXBN9m1krWCi8kEF8w97FWOZ3P8l0p3Vdu1W8ZZGJ7WmED3YSyRNlq_pzVCYmE3T5szWNiEvj_MIisAFUmnwof3_KnPlNyES3zyqqowmDB-upIkMvqJNmEjdhl5svm3-b0b5mElSfQZSzkEjCII7ifPERstsHad2W5oORhlOSoqy01JRX4XfIO-cdwzoJK_RuRyMWCIuJ4UilV3aXg0wayeAG4bYMXBszrV1GSLtLkNiWjlMDstETIy0m_ngQRcZvLQf0tXFk2F1XbXyinW3sBdNkGPOmu0vWL0vxhAKmLFC2S0p2UKgKoDw&scope=openid%20profile&expires_in=7200&token_type=Bearer&state=2a91a1122b2e4d7687d96f8a40b1d066&id_token=eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6Ik16ZzVPRFl5TkROQlJUVkNPRVEwTmpBNE1qUkZORGMxUVROQ1JqTkZOall4TVVJd1JqQTJRUSJ9.eyJuaWNrbmFtZSI6InNlcmdpdS5pb251dDk4IiwibmFtZSI6IlNlcmdpdSBNb2xuYXIiLCJwaWN0dXJlIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9zLmdyYXZhdGFyLmNvbS9hdmF0YXIvMDIwMzAwZjFmZDgyNjA3NTI1NWFjOTRhMWM1ODRmMjY_cz00ODAmcj1wZyZkPWh0dHBzJTNBJTJGJTJGY2RuLmF1dGgwLmNvbSUyRmF2YXRhcnMlMkZzZS5wbmciLCJ1cGRhdGVkX2F0IjoiMjAxOS0xMi0yOFQxNDozMjoxNC40MzNaIiwiaXNzIjoiaHR0cHM6Ly9kZXYtc2Vyai5ldS5hdXRoMC5jb20vIiwic3ViIjoiYXV0aDB8NWUwNTQ0MzEyODRkNDcwZWI5MGQ5MzZhIiwiYXVkIjoiUjdmeGdITmtQRWoyVlgxSDdxNEZwMGoyWG5TcWF1ZEoiLCJpYXQiOjE1Nzc1NDg5NjMsImV4cCI6MTU3NzU4NDk2MywiYXRfaGFzaCI6IkN2OWFxdHJXbnIyR2RsZ2xkYjJNdHciLCJub25jZSI6ImIzMTkwMjliM2Y1NDQ3YjFiOWEwYWNjMzM0ODkyNjAxIn0.FbZuWPwn3zBNn_7hB6fYDQ45vyjyVKDXb3GOJFAI86eDC9I1cmzb3ugl8aGQybGirR60yAprRfNu7CfHiZ-4KfUAGItakG49i-NMzztedYAvA7ipiV7aWx4yA9_Y9PHKczD0NymnYj7U72vqkwnwvvJWk1f6eRx8e1cXZHAapGe9k-g5lazLAnrRAKXmw-75VyalPASRB3V9P59h0Ob-TyLwjCCDzIQxKnKPL9XvvYIcLocPNmDfj89Z1XBFeMTXHGiWfg2Swk9PnN6DucYMq-SYdSWIb3CgtOJ-R1HCK7iSsR0lQFnCVnmPTwr_HovwQoFqqFydSCUXxUOeRAYkAQ
```

Comment: Actually I found something: this is caused by **loggedIn ? resolve() : this.oidcFacade.signinRedirect();** from **auth.service**. This acts like the **loggedIn** from **oidcFacade** is never true and always call the signinRedirect function.

Comment: And if I'm using **this.oidcFacade.signinPopup()** instead, some pop-ups are displayed and after that, I'm logged in successfully but the pop-ups are still appearing.

Comment: It looks like you are getting the tokens back correctly, which suggests that this problem is with how your callback is being handled. I am not familiar with using both OIDC and Auth0 like this, it may be easier just to use the official Auth0 quickstart. https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/angular2/01-login

Is there a reason why you are not following that guide?

Comment: Can you please let me know your logic to initiate the sign in flow? I mean after you get the access token, the sign in callback function should be executed and it should redirect you back to the angular page from where you started. It might be possible that user details are not available and it is again initiating the sign in flow

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue? For me this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$ is always false. Do I need to use ngrx actions? After callback, I'm redirecting it to home component, and in home component i'm trying to use this.oidcFacade.loggedIn$ and identity$ but everything is null for me.